# Ruby replace text within single quotes or backticks for html tag

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

Hello I am trying to build a simple action in Ruby that takes one string like

`result = "This is my javascript variable 'var first = 1 + 1;' and here is another 'var second = 2 + 2;' and that's it!"`

So basically I would like to take the text within single quotes `'` or  backticks `` ` `` and and replace it by:

`<code>original text</code>` note I'm replacing it by an opening and closing `code` tag

Just like in markdown

so I would have a result like

`result = "This is my javascript variable <code>var first = 1 + 1;<code> and here is another <code>var second = 2 + 2;</code> and that's it"`

If it's possible to run this natively without the need of any extra gem it would be great :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need to iterate the string and parse it. While you can do non-greedy regex matches, e.g. `result.gsub!(/'([^']*)'/, '<code>\1</code>')` you might find the result might not behave correctly in corner-cases.

Answer (score 1):

Without any other advanced requirement

```
>> result.gsub(/\s+'/,"<code>").gsub(/'\s+/,"</code>")
=> "This is my javascript variable<code>var first = 1 + 1;</code>and here is another<code>var second = 2 + 2;</code>and that's it!"
```

Comment: thanks for your help @kurumi, it seems that when the string's last char is a single quote it doesn't close with `</code>` but @DarkDust methods worked pretty well, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to come-up with a character as a delimiter for your code, which you don't use otherwise..

Why? because of all the corner cases.  E.g. the following string

```
result = "This's my javascript variable 'var first = 1 + 1;' and here is another 'var second = 2 + 2;' and that's it!"
```

which would otherwise produce:

```
"This<code>s my javascript variable </code>var first = 1 + 1;<code> and here is another </code>var second = 2 + 2;<code> and that</code>s it!"
```

Total garbage out..

However if you use a unique character as a delimiter that's otherwise not used, you can create a non-greedy RegExp which will do the search/replace

e.g. using a # character to delimit the code:

```
  "This's my javascript variable #var first = 1 + 1;# and here is another #var second = 2 + 2;# and that's it!"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tilo, fortunately in this case I know `'` will be specifically used for this. But I will keep this in my in case some problem appear, cheers

Comment: well, you're using the ' also as an apostrophe in plain English text...  That causes a problem! What I meant is that you should use a character which is used exclusively only for the purpose of delimiting the code, and which is not used for other purposes (e.g. in the text) otherwise..